# Ethereum address not find

Tags: wallets

Any one tell me how to know about which website generates this ETH address:

```
0x6fdd1c34b75b8638d3806adecbcbbc61ed4ed3b3
```

Comment: Search on etherscan

Comment: From an address there's no way to determine which wallet created it (unless there were a well known bug in the wallet).

Answer (score 2):

This address does not have any incoming or outgoing transactions. Unless you own the private key for this address, or someone sent it to you, it likely belongs to nobody. Any wallet software that is able to generate Ethereum private keys can potentially generate this address.